# Inserting data from Google Search API into MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, mysqli

I hope all of you can help me and understand my question. As you can see here i want to get the data from google search API and save into my database and display it too. I already use the ajax. html but i got error.
The data i want to save is snippet , title and link. I dont want save all the data I got from. I think my problem is how to pass variable from javascript to mysql

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Search API</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="mySubmit" onclick="myFunction()" >Search</button>
<div id="content">
<div id="content1">
</div>
<script id="searchme"></script>
<script>

    function hndlr(response) 
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <response.items.length; i++) 
                        {
                            var item = response.items[i];     
                            var api = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML +="<br>"+"<b>"+ item.title + "</b>"+"<br>" +item.snippet  + "<br>"+"<a href='"+item.link+"'>"+item.link+"</a>";
                            var link = item.link; 
                            var snippet =item.snippet;
                            var title =item.title;


                        }
            }

    function myFunction() 
            {
                var query = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
                var cx ='004123968310343535430%3Aaxml6iel9yo'
                var key ='AIzaSyDxPcphnrcN9_dfkRkFTbwkv44m1-HI1Hg'
                var search_query = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?callback=hndlr&sort=date&cx="+cx+"&key="+key+"&q="+query;
                document.getElementById('searchme').src = search_query; 
            }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I already post the question before, but someone said its already duplicate. But I think he dont understand my question at all. If you test this php first i think u understand what i want

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do trick after getting a result using a callback function.

```
function myCallBackCustomFunction(callback) 
       {
           //DO YOUR STUFF FOR api then call your server to store data    

          yourCustomsaveFunction(callback);
       }
function yourCustomsaveFunction(googlevars)
{
 $.ajax("your url?myparameters="+googlevars, {
  success: function(data) {
    //your data save msg if any
  },
  error: function() {
     //your error msg if any
  }
```

});
    }

you can change ajax method from GET to POST if you wish.

Comment: Actually i already callback function in myFunction, did i need to do it again?

Comment: nope... just get a result from callback function and pass it on your server to save the result.

Comment: What u mean by that? Can u give me example?

Comment: @Rushdiey I had updated my answer. I hope you get more clearly.

Comment: function myCallBackCustomFunction(callback) 
       {
                                                        var title =item.title;

          yourCustomsaveFunction(callback);
       }
function yourCustomsaveFunction(googlevars)
{
 $.ajax("ajax.php?title="+googlevars, {
  success: function(data) {
    //your data save msg if any
  },
  error: function() {
     //your error msg if any
  }

Is it like this ?